# Stop Passenger from leaking environment variables on failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Well this is embarrassing.  If for some reason my developer sends a bad build of our rails app to the production server, passenger may not be able to load. When that happens, web requests to passenger dump an error page with all of the variables in .env.  As he prefers to put all of his secrets in .env like API keys to remote services, this is potentially a big security hole.

Is there any way to turn this behaviour off?  We're using nginx.  We're adding a staging server to the workflow to avoid pushing bad releases, but still, this seems like it shouldn't be happening.

Thanks. Here's the relevant portion of the nginx.conf file:

```
http {
  passenger_root /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40;
  passenger_ruby /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@XXX/wrappers/ruby;

server {
  listen              443;
  server_name         www.X.com;

  root                /home/X/current/public;
  passenger_enabled   on;
  ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn [passenger_friendly_error_pages off](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerFriendlyErrorPages). Since 4.0.42, it's off by default on production.